Is the black fluidic substance surrounding stolen armor in The Predator (2018) Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15?
Is the black fluidic substance surrounding stolen armor in The Predator (2018) Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15?
The Predator (2018) the end scene has a Yautja storage pod carrying stolen armor [which transforms into Yautja-hologram garment for human being].
When the technician opens the pod "black goo substance" from  inside it disappears to reveal the stolen armor.
In Alien: Romulus the synthetic-human, Rook, has a short discussion on Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15… (aka: "black goo").

It strikes me as scifi storage foam.  You don't want armor damaged in transport.

As long as Ridley Scott continues to be involved in the making of the Alien films (he was a producer on Alien: Romulus), it's unlikely that there'll be any official link between those films and the Predator films. He regarded the idea of Alien vs. Predator as "daft," couldn't bring himself to watch that film, blamed it for nearly killing the Alien franchise, and gave Damon Lindelof (the co-writer of Prometheus) a withering look when he briefly brought it up during the production of Prometheus.
It can't even be taken for granted that James Cameron's widely-lauded Aliens film is canon to the four films Scott himself was directly involved with (Alien, Prometheus, Covenant and Romulus), as far as Scott is concerned, never mind any of the Predator films. The existence of the Queen as part of the Xenomorph life cycle was not acknowledged in any of those four films.
Relevant quotes and links regarding Scott's views on Alien vs. Predator can be found in my previous answer to an older question.

Please clarify: the black goo from Alien Prometheus (Ridley Scott) and Alien Romulus (Fede Alvarez). was "non-canon" to The Predator (2018, Shane Black) correct??

That is what I am saying, yes.

Does Predator universe (which is canon to Predator) have games or tv series or comics which detail a black fluidic substance, excluding (2018 Shane Black)?

I don't know of any notable black fluid within the Predator franchise, but I'm not well-versed in the expanded universe. I've seen all the films and read some of the comics, and that's about it. Don't think I've played any of the games, yet, though I probably will at some point.

The best thing to come out of AVP was the Kenner toys.
